Does Verse 29 of Mtt 26 have relevance to Verse 27?
We read in Mtt 26:27-29 ( NIV):

27.Then he took a cup, and when he had given thanks, he gave it to them, saying, “Drink from it, all of you. 28 This is my blood of the[b] covenant, which is poured out for many for the forgiveness of sins. 29 I tell you, I will not drink from this fruit of the vine from now on until that day when I drink it new with you in my Father’s kingdom.”.

Note the phrase ' took a cup and when he had given thanks ' . Adult Jews are believed to have consumed four cups  of wine per head, during the Passover Meal. Going by Verse 28, transubstantiation took place as Jesus blessed the cup of wine and distributed it in such a manner that all the participants partook of the same cup. But in Verse 29 Jesus appears to be referring to wine in purely material sense. That would imply  that the group had earlier consumed three cups of  wine per head as part of the Thanksgiving ceremony. My question is : Does Verse 29 of Mtt 26 have relevance to Thanksgiving in Verse 27 ?

There is a connection (relevance) because there is a progression.

1: In any sequence of events, an initial action or event sets
the stage for subsequent actions or events. An initial action is
foundational to anything that follows.
2: Subsequent actions or events build upon the initial
action. (Thus, creating a progression). Each step is
connected to the previous one, forming a coherent sequence.
3: The final outcome or event is the culmination of the
preceding actions. It is inherently linked to the initial action and
the steps that followed, as they collectively lead to the final
result.

The act of thanksgiving in Verse 27 is part of a logical progression that leads to the future promise in Verse 29
Luke 22:15

And he said to them, “I have earnestly desired to eat this Passover
with you before I suffer.

Thanksgiving sets the stage. There is a progression. Jesus gave thanks before the suffering. Before the final act. His thanksgiving is an immediate act that blesses the cup signifying the start of the new covenant. Verse 29 on the other hand, looks forward to the ultimate fulfillment of this new covenant. In the kingdom of God. The progression is from the present act to future realization.
Matthew 26:27-29

27 And he took a cup, and when he had given thanks he gave it to them,
saying, “Drink of it, all of you, 28 for this is my blood of the
covenant, which is poured out for many for the forgiveness of sins. 29
I tell you I will not drink again of this fruit of the vine until that
day when I drink it new with you in my Father's kingdom.”

Verse 27:
Jesus gives thanks before distributing the cup.
Verse 28:
Jesus explains: the wine represents His blood. His blood is shed for the forgiveness of sins. A new covenant.
This is all about forgiveness and redemption.

Christ redeemed us from the curse of the law by becoming a curse for
us—for it is written, “Cursed is everyone who is hanged on a tree”— (Galatians 3:13)

Verse 29:
Our focus is shifted to the future. Jesus will not drink from the fruit of the vine until He drinks it new in His Father’s kingdom. This is presented as something that will happen in the future.

What we know:

During the Passover meal, it was customary for Jews to drink four
cups of wine.

Third cup:
It is likely here that Jesus gives thanks. The institution of a new covenant.
The cup Jesus took in Verse 27 is often identified as the third cup, known as the “Cup of Redemption.”

It is believed that it is the Cup of Redemption that Jesus instructed
the disciples to partake of in the last supper, since both accounts in
Matthew 26:27 and Luke 22:19 describe the cup being taken after the
meal. [1]


The Cup of Redemption traditionally signifies the slaying of the
Passover lamb that spared the Israelites from the 10th plague of the
slaying of the first born. This cup traditionally remembers how the
Lord redeems Israel with an outstretched arm. [1]

In other words, the blood of the Passover Lamb provided protection for the faithful Israelites and Egyptians in ancient Egypt. So as the blood of Jesus offers covering for both Jewish and Gentile believers in the present day.
The main course was consumed at the conclusion.
Fourth cup:
The main course eaten there was still one cup to drink.
The fourth cup is known as the “The Cup of Hillel" (Praise or Acceptance).

I tell you I will not drink again of this fruit of the vine until
that day when I drink it new with you in my Father's kingdom.”

In this context, having partaken of the third cup, he refers to the fourth cup.
At this point, did Jesus finish the meal? There was still one cup to drink:

At this point, Jesus and his Apostles make their way to the Garden of
Gethsemani (read Matthew 26:36-46). Here we read that Jesus prays
three times for the cup that he must drink. The cup (or chalice in
some translations) is the fourth cup, the final cup of the Passover
meal. Between the giving of his body at the Last Supper as the
sacrifice and one of the cups as his own blood, Jesus classifies his
body as the New Passover. Once the meal is over, his blood will be
poured out, and Jesus will be dead. He does not finish the meal in the
Upper Room because it will finish with his death on the cross. [2]


It is worth noting that the traditional Jewish Passover meal holds a different perspective in Christianity, although some Christians do observe the Passover meal in their practice.
In Christianity, Jesus commanded two ceremonial practices: Baptism and Eucharist. The Last Supper marks the origin of the Eucharist, instituted by Jesus Christ Himself. It is also referred to as Holy Communion. The bread and wine are seen as the real presence of Jesus, offering spiritual nourishment.
Matthew 26:27 emphasizes death - the sacrifice of Jesus, who shed His blood to establish the new covenant. Drinking the wine symbolizes the union with Christ through His blood, granting forgiveness of sin.
Hebrew 9:14-22 states:

14 How much more, then, will the blood of Christ, who through the eternal Spirit offered himself unblemished to God, cleanse our consciences from acts that lead to death, so that we may serve the living God! 15 For this reason Christ is the mediator of a new covenant, that those who are called may receive the promised eternal inheritance—now that he has died as a ransom to set them free from the sins committed under the first covenant. 16 In the case of a will, it is necessary to prove the death of the one who made it, 17 because a will is in force only when somebody has died; it never takes effect while the one who made it is living. 18 This is why even the first covenant was not put into effect without blood. 19 When Moses had proclaimed every command of the law to all the people, he took the blood of calves, together with water, scarlet wool and branches of hyssop, and sprinkled the scroll and all the people. 20 He said, “This is the blood of the covenant, which God has commanded you to keep.” 21 In the same way, he sprinkled with the blood both the tabernacle and everything used in its ceremonies. 22 In fact, the law requires that nearly everything be cleansed with blood, and without the shedding of blood there is no forgiveness.

Matthew 26:29 emphasizes hope and victory. At that time, it will no longer be a private feast, but a grand feast of communion, as described in Revelation 19:7-9

7 Let us rejoice and be glad
and give him glory!
For the wedding of the Lamb has come,
and his bride has made herself ready.
8 Fine linen, bright and clean,
was given her to wear.”
(Fine linen stands for the righteous acts of God’s holy people.)
9 Then the angel said to me, “Write this: Blessed are those who are invited to the wedding supper of the Lamb!” And he added, “These are the true words of God.”

